# how can i boot to normal user on live USB

Tags: boot, live-usb, lightdm

I installed ubuntustudio 64bit 14.04 on a usb stick. The aim is to use it as a normally installed session but with the added benefit of keeping all my OS in a usb and using any pc available.

This means that I don't want all the tweaks and settings that are available on the liveUSB.
The differences I have spotted so far that  I would like to revert are the following:

- booting goes directly to the live session, bypassing `lightDM`. I want to be greeted by the lightDM and choose my user and type in my password.
- liveUSB boots to the "ubuntu-studio" user, who is simply the live session user. I want to boot to a normal user account.
- `sudo ubuntu-studio` uses an empty password. I should obviously remove that user account once my normal user account is up and running.

So, I guess the root of the changes I need to make the system boot to `lightDM` or whatever else ubuntustudio is using.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can set a password with the following command `sudo passwd ubuntu-studio` you will be asked for a password. You will need to set up a casper partition for a persistent session see here on doing so https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Comment: Basically, when you need to create a new user and then, next time you boot up, log into that user instead. You should be presented options either on shut down, startup, or both after creating the new user account.

Comment: @mchid I have created the new user - my normal user, but still after a restart I get into the live session again. Also I do have persistence enabled. I have tested that by creating a file and rebooting. The file was still there after the reboot.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: @nass: What if you go into user account control and toggle auto-login for ubuntu-studio? Also make sure you set a pass for ubuntu-studio as well.